# Only including products in a collection based on their category sort position

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection

When building a product collection, is there a way to only include products with a category sort position greater/less/is than (x)?

I've tried searching but couldn't find a case of where anyone had asked this before.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('neq' => 1))
    ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'asc')
    ->load();
```

In the above product collection, we only want to include products if their sort position in the category is 0. We are forcing a large amount of products to appear at the end of the category by setting their position to 1000.

I suppose I could create a custom attribute with something like a Yes/No value and set all the products to Yes that we want to include in this product collection including it with a `addAttributeToFilter` but was hoping for a less fiddly/time-consuming way if possible.

Comment: Had you time to test my suggestion? I'm bit piss** off b/c of downvote and just want to have some feedback. (For me this works with flat table on and off)

Comment: Actually, sorry for delay, we were literally playing around with this and had to make some extra customisation to get it to what we want and I was impressed with your solution, at the time of you answering, I was almost certain this was what we needed but just needed some time to work with it (which we have now). I can assure you that I didn't downvote your answer below and have no idea why someone would have. I am just going to check what we implemented yesterday to your answer.

Comment: I know that you haven't downvoted - you were not online at this time :) Nice to to help you. And thanks for this question ... this is useful for us too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check items data, you'll find something like this `'cat_index_position' => '0'`. This data is added through an `INNER JOIN 'catalog_category_product_index' AS 'cat_index'` and isn't an product EAV attribute, so `addAttributeToFilter('cat_index_position', 0)` will not work, but you can do it in this way:

```
$collection->getSelect()->where('cat_index.position = ?', 0);
```

**Edit:** you have call this before `load()` the collection ...

Comment: Any reasons for downvote?

Comment: Not sure but I didn't downvote it. I replied to your comment above on my question.

Comment: I upvoted and marked as correct answer. We used exactly what you suggested to do what we were after, amongst the rest of the product collection e.g. `$productColl->getSelect()->where('cat_index.position = ?', 0);` - Thanks!